# In thymeleaf spring boot, dynamic carousel slider does not work

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my spring boot thymeleaf, this following code is slider does not work well.Show the result in image.[image]
What wrong with in that code. Please Check it out.

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

     <th:block th:each="picture, iterstat : ${package.picture}"> 
      <li  data-target="#jsaAboutCarousel" th:attr="data-slide-to=${iterstat.index}" th:class="${iterstat.index}== 0  ? 'active':''"></li>

      </th:block>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->



    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div th:each="picture, iterstat : ${package.picture}">  

      <th:block th:class="${iterstat.index}== 0  ? 'item':'item active'">
        <img th:src="@{${baseurl}+'/backend/getPackageImagePath/' + ${picture}}" class="img-responsive" />

    </th:block>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#jsaAboutCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#jsaAboutCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can add `class` attribute in `th:block` tag.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div th:each="picture, iterstat : ${package.picture}">
        <th:block th:class="${iterstat.index}== 0  ? 'item':'item active'">
            <img th:src="@{${baseurl}+'/backend/getPackageImagePath/' + ${picture}}" class="img-responsive" />
        </th:block>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try changing like this.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div th:each="picture, iterstat : ${package.picture}" th:class="${iterstat.index}== 0  ? 'item':'item active'">
        <img th:src="@{${baseurl}+'/backend/getPackageImagePath/' + ${picture}}" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow this was hard nut. But in the end this works for me. "imageURls" are a List of Strings passed from java controller to html file. Itereated over in the carousel using thymeleaf. Using bootstrap carousel.

```html
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item" th:each="url: ${imageUrls}" th:classappend ="${urlStat.first} ? active : ''">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" th:src="${url}" height="600px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```